# React Router with params navigatin back needs double click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, router

Simple question.

When I'm in a for instance `/dashboard` router and I click on `<Link to="/users/:userID" >` router and try to  go back to `/dashboard` it works wine , but when from `/users/:userID` router I navigate to  another `/users/:userID` router and try to go back I need to click the back button twice , any idea why?

e.g.

> /dashboard -> /users/1 and back ( 1 click needed )
>
> /dashboard -> /users/1  - > /users/2 and back to /users/1  ( 2 clicks
>   needed )

Here is my Route in App.js

```
<Route path='/users/:userId'  render={()=><User/>} />
```

Here is my  User.jsx render()

```
render() {
    let movie = this.props.thisUserIdData;
    const { match } = this.props;
    console.log(match);
    return (
        <div> .... </div>
         )
}
```

and the componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.loadData(this.props.match.params.userId); 
   //using redux and  axios to  get data 
}
```

Comment: I would log in componentDidMount and see if it is loading twice for the users/2 route.  I haven't run into this, but a guess is that it would be fixed by changing the route to use component: <Route path='/users/:userId'  component={User} />

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation with nested `onClick` action.

For example:

```
<div onClick={() => push(`/user/${id}`)}>
   <button onClick={() => push(`/user/${id}`)}>to user</button>
</div>
```